# Django signals: Check if the data inside of ManyToManyField is change/updated

Tags: python, django, signals

how can I check if the objects inside of ManyToManyField is change or updated while still accessing the main Model where the manytomanyfield is placed.
Here is the example of code:

```
class Student:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=False)

class Room:
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student,  related_name="list_of_students")
```

I tried the `m2m_changed` but it only recieve those signals when there's a Newly added/updated/deleted on `students` field.

I want to get the `Room` model where the student is selected at `students` field.

```
s1 = Student.objects.first()
s1.name = "John Doe"
s1.save()
'''prints the data with Room model on it.'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pre_save` or `post_save` signal for `Student` model, access to all `rooms` and make some logic.

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def handle_student_changes(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created: # check if new instance created and exit if yes
        return
    rooms = instance.list_of_students.all() # get all rooms for student
    print(rooms) # or make some other logic
```

PS
`related_name` in `students` m2m field probably should be named `rooms` or `students_rooms`